# Возможно-лучшее

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, как написать слово «возможно-лучшее» в таком контексте:  «обращение к такому типу обоснования, как апелляция к возможно-лучшему»?

Answer (score 1):

В этом выражении "возможно" употребляется как наречие при субстантивированном прилагательном, употреблённом в форме превосходной степени сравнения, и является обстоятельством. Дефис не нужен.

ВОЗМО́ЖНО.

1. нареч. к возможный, употр. при сравн. Возможно скорее. Возможно лучшие условия.
2. вводное слово. Может быть (разг.). Возможно, меня не будет дома в это время.
   (Толковый словарь Ушакова)

Comment: На мой вкус, по смыслу фразы больше подходит сочетание "наивозможно лучшему". Звучит несколько устарело, но устраняет двусмысленность между предположением (возможно, лучшему) и максимумом качества (возможно лучшему, лучшему, насколько возможно). to behemotus: Мне кажется, именно стремление избежать этой двусмысленности и сподвигло автора на дефисное написание. Потому и предложил решение. Но вы правы, это скорее комментарий к уже данному правильному ответу, чем сам ответ. Переоформил.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень поняла смысл фразы. Если это не какой-нибудь термин, то слово "возможно" пишется раздельно и выделяется запятыми, так как является вводным. Если у Вас фраза из текста по какой-нибудь новой дисциплине, обратитесь к терминологическому словарю или скажите, хотя бы, к какой отрасли знания относится. Логику изучала давно, но такого термина не помню.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь что-то с грамматикой.Слова «возможно-лучшее» я,признаюсь, не слышала. Может быть, слово "возможно" вводное? Очень трудно понять смысл фразы.